# c++ - OpenGL movement with deltatime

Tags: c++, opengl

So, I started programming again in C++ and trying things out with OpenGL. Currently I have a basic application where I just want to move the camera with keys. I read many article about this, but still I have problem with the movement, I guess because even if only a little, but they differs from my program. First I made a 60 fps limit and calculated the speed with deltatime, but the movement was laggy. Now I turned off FPS limiting, but now it runs at around 4000 FPS, so deltatime is most of the time 0 or 1, so the movement is really really slow. I'm sure I don't understand something about the concept, but I need to point it out.

The main loop:

```
while (running) {
    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) {

        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            running = false;

            break;
        } else {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    } else {
        clock_t last = clock();
        deltaTime = last-start;

        //if ((double)deltaTime >= 16.666666666) {
        fps++;
        millis += deltaTime;
        start = last;

        if (millis > 1000) {
            millis = 0;
            std::cout << "FPS: " << fps << std::endl;
            fps = 0;
        }

        openglContext.renderScene();
        //}
    }
}
```

WndProc key handler:

```
float speed = 5.0f;

...

case WM_KEYDOWN:
    switch(wParam) {
        case 0x57:
            openglContext.updateCoordinates(0.0f, 0.0f, ((float)deltaTime / 1000.0f * speed), glm::radians(angle));
            break;
    }
    break;
```

I know it's not perfect, but as I wrote before I tried many "solutions".
Hope someone can help. Thanks in advance!

Solution:

There is still many to do, but for now it's perfect.

```
LARGE_INTEGER start;
LARGE_INTEGER frequency;
QueryPerformanceFrequency(&frequency);
QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

while (running) {

    ...

        LARGE_INTEGER current;
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&current);
        dt = ((double)(current.QuadPart - start.QuadPart) / (double)frequency.QuadPart);
        QueryPerformanceCounter(&start);

        ... key handling
        ... render
        ...
```

Comment: Have a read of:  http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/

Comment: @RichardCritten: That is a really good link. But I would suggest not to use this strategy for camera control when responsiveness of the application is a factor.

Comment: Actually I have read it too, but it seemed a bit too complicated for me, but maybe I will try it out.

Comment: @BDL I treat the camera as one of my physical game objects it seems responsive enough to me. Pressing a key gives the camera an instant velocity in the appropriate direction. Every time the camera moves itself (it's a game object) it resets is own velocity to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem that `delta_time` is either 0 or 1 happens because of the generally low resolution of `std::clock()`. In most cases, the minimal time that can be measured is around 0.01 seconds, which is way to less for a rendering application. [Reference](https://www.guyrutenberg.com/2007/09/10/resolution-problems-in-clock/)

Depending on your system and on the compiler used, there are several alternatives that will allow you to measure timings with higher precision.

- (C++11 `high_resolution_clock`)[http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/high_resolution_clock]
- (`QueryPerformanceCounter` in Windows)[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn553408(v=vs.85).aspx]

Comment: Thanks, I will check it out.

Comment: I accepted your answer, it wasn't too easy to implement, but now it works. There is still many to do, but for now it's perfect for me, also I update my question with my solution.